# How to get values in variable from jsonObject?

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I have response like this from my Soap Web Service as follows:

```
    [{"msg":"1,UDDAIPUR","Value1":null,"Value2":null,"Value3":null,"Value4":null,"Value5":null,"Value6":null,"Value7":null,"Value8":null,"Value9":null,"Value10":null}]
```

Below is my AsyncTask -

```
//String TAG_IDS And TAG_NAMES
private static final String TAG_ID_fillstateid = "nSerialNo";

//TO call web service for City
class async_fillCity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, method_name__fillcity);
        request.addProperty(parameter_fillcity, "1");//add the parameters

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);//set soap version
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        try {
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
            androidHttpTransport.call(soap_action_fillcity, envelope);  // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
            //SoapPrimitive prim = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();  // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            //resultstate = prim.toString();
            resultcity = response.getPropertyAsString(0).toString();

            if (resultcity != null) {
                try {

                    JSONArray resultarray = new JSONArray(resultcity);
                    for (int i = 0; i < resultarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = resultarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String idCity = c.getString(TAG_ID_fillstateid);
                        String nameCity = (c.getString(TAG_Name_fillstatename));
                        HashMap<String, String> hashstate = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hashstate.put(TAG_ID_fillstateid, idCity);
                        hashstate.put(TAG_Name_fillstatename, nameCity);
                        resultListstate.add(hashstate);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultcity;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, resultListstate, R.layout.activity_showspinner_state, new String[]{TAG_ID_fillstateid, TAG_Name_fillstatename}, new int[]{R.id.textidstate, R.id.textnamestate});

        city.setAdapter(adapter);

        city.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                TextView txtid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textidstate);
                City = txtid.getText().toString();
                // Call web service for district
                //calldistt();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        super.onPostExecute(result1);

    }
}
```

I am getting error:

> "org.json.JSONException: No value for nSerialNo"

Comment: In your json result there is no value like - "nSerialNo", that's why you getting error.

Comment: Theres no such key `nSerialNo` inside the JSON

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you give any solution how i get both cityid and cityname in String type of variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get id and city separately like this -

```
                JSONArray resultarray = new JSONArray(resultcity);
                for (int i = 0; i < resultarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = resultarray.getJSONObject(i);
                   String idCity = c.getString(msg);}
```

Now you get City id and city name in idCity string, now you have to split string by commoa (,) like this

```
String[] namesList = idCity.split(",");
String id = namesList[0];
String cityName = namesList[1];
```

Happy to Happy...

Comment: Thanks Shane you saved my time. I am using web service first time and again i stuck because i want to populate cityName in spinner but its giving error.

Comment: Hi Shane now i am getting this error in Exception will you plaease solve this "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference" 

resultListstate.add(hashstate); giving null

Comment: Make a list of String type- List<String> cityname = new ArrayList<String>(); then add data to list in doInBackgroundMethod below idCity string like - cityname.add(idCity); then setadapter to spinner like - spinner.setAdapter(new "YOURADATER"(this, <LISTNAME>)); here LISTNAME is cityname

Comment: Thanks Shane but this not what i want. I want to set both cityId and cityName in TextView then i will show only cityName in spinner after that i want to populate another spinner for local place of selected city

Comment: I want to add both value in HashMap and then populate in spinner in onPostExecute